# Foreign keys info in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, schema

How to get the name, referenced schema and table for a all foreign keys in a SQL Sever database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old School

```
SELECT 
  [ForeignKey] = f.name
, [TableName] = OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id), COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,fc.parent_column_id)
, [ReferenceTableName] = OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id)
, ReferenceColumnName = COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id, fc.referenced_column_id)
FROM 
sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
```

New School:

From

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175805%28SQL.80%29.aspx

```
SELECT 
      KCU1.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA as 'CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA_1'
    , KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS 'FK_CONSTRAINT_NAME'
    , KCU1.TABLE_SCHEMA  as 'TABLE_SCHEMA_1'
    , KCU1.TABLE_NAME AS 'FK_TABLE_NAME'
    , KCU1.COLUMN_NAME AS 'FK_COLUMN_NAME'
    , KCU1.ORDINAL_POSITION AS 'FK_ORDINAL_POSITION'
    , '----------' as Sep1
    , KCU2.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS 'UQ_CONSTRAINT_NAME'
    , KCU2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA  as 'CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA_2'
    , KCU1.TABLE_SCHEMA  as 'TABLE_SCHEMA_2'
    , KCU2.TABLE_NAME AS 'UQ_TABLE_NAME'
    , KCU2.COLUMN_NAME AS 'UQ_COLUMN_NAME'
    , KCU2.ORDINAL_POSITION AS 'UQ_ORDINAL_POSITION'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU1
ON KCU1.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = RC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG 
   AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = RC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
   AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU2
ON KCU2.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = 
RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG 
   AND KCU2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 
RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
   AND KCU2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = 
RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
   AND KCU2.ORDINAL_POSITION = KCU1.ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Comment: I strongly prefer "old school"